# Why cant i plot this?

Tags: r, dataframe

im trying to plot longitude and latitude values using ggplot, i have selected the $longitude and $latitude from a dataframe like this to avoid getting missing values (the dataframe has some incorrect values that screwed the plot on previous tries):

```
drug_cases_lat_long<-filter(drug_violation_cases, drug_violation_cases$Latitude>=41 | drug_violation_cases$Longitude<0)
```

then i created another dataframe using just these two values:

```
drug_caseslat <- data.frame("Longitude" = drug_cases_lat_long$Longitude,  "Latitude" = drug_cases_lat_long$Latitude, stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
```

and finally tried to plot using ggplot() but all i get is a blank thing with no points in it...

```
ggplot(data = drug_caseslat, aes(x = Longitude, y = Latitude))
```

This is how the new dataframe (drug_caseslat) is set:

```
 > str(drug_caseslat)
'data.frame':   14645 obs. of  2 variables:
 $ Longitude: num  -71.1 -71.1 -71.1 -71.1 -71.1 ...
 $ Latitude : num  42.3 42.3 42.3 42.3 42.3 ...
```

I just realise there is no `geom_point()` in it but even using `geom_point()`, the plot has only two points

more about the structure of the data:

```
    dput(head(drug_caseslat, n = 100))
structure(list(Longitude = c(-71.08431925, -71.08431925, -71.07085307, 
-71.07618683, -71.07618683, -71.07317861, -71.06206351, -71.06670845, 
-71.04155054, -71.11950948, -71.11950948, -71.11950948, -71.09722321, 
-71.16386818, -71.07182739, -71.08624927, -71.12928626, -71.12928626, 
-71.12928626, -71.06453754, -71.09825252, -71.09825252, -71.09825252, 
-71.06110712, -71.0581068, -71.13269192, -71.04736497, -71.07085307, 
-71.08200715, -71.08200715, -71.11680936, -71.11680936, -71.07024947, 
-71.07024947, -71.05667294, -71.01977077, -71.01977077, -71.075067, 
-71.075067, -71.05731757, -71.06169938, -71.10057355, -71.05467933, 
-71.10429211, -71.10429211, -71.10429211, -71.10429211, -71.06213513, 
-71.09829029, -71.05700823, -71.07368297, -71.08563401, -71.07754554, 
-71.07754554, -71.07754554, -71.062044, -71.03930935, -71.05682769, 
-71.05682769, -71.1504985, -71.0474205, -71.0749171, -71.0749171, 
-71.0749171, -71.08635771, -71.03525734, -71.132027, -70.99878996, 
-71.05354012, -71.07167184, -71.118879, -71.118879, -71.05481095, 
-71.07416742, -71.03475103, -71.03475103, -71.07239518, -71.05572699, 
-71.05572699, -71.07139645, -71.02929361, -71.02929361, -71.02929361, 
-71.07256779, -71.08485404, -71.08248425, -71.07194742, -71.0722749, 
-71.06962216, -71.10220402, -71.05467933, -71.06588201, -71.05593196, 
-71.06771838, -71.06252889, -71.07108773, -71.07108773, -71.07108773, 
-71.07108773, -71.08454012), Latitude = c(42.30676881, 42.30676881, 
42.33152148, 42.31580934, 42.31580934, 42.31224532, 42.35521429, 
42.35678442, 42.36967378, 42.25378838, 42.25378838, 42.25378838, 
42.28281074, 42.34934252, 42.33176796, 42.29013465, 42.28537376, 
42.28537376, 42.28537376, 42.35238395, 42.32492305, 42.32492305, 
42.32492305, 42.32219952, 42.32445145, 42.28219943, 42.28076737, 
42.33152148, 42.32924494, 42.32924494, 42.29233925, 42.29233925, 
42.32587659, 42.32587659, 42.2972764, 42.38279978, 42.38279978, 
42.335007, 42.335007, 42.31249706, 42.34491581, 42.32281495, 
42.34128751, 42.26452149, 42.26452149, 42.26452149, 42.26452149, 
42.35637531, 42.31580852, 42.37915224, 42.32014754, 42.32866284, 
42.31440563, 42.31440563, 42.31440563, 42.3649755, 42.38260122, 
42.33814782, 42.33814782, 42.349056, 42.33125163, 42.33511904, 
42.33511904, 42.33511904, 42.29530363, 42.33147957, 42.27457154, 
42.38974276, 42.32737965, 42.3322228, 42.279922, 42.279922, 42.36569971, 
42.30334343, 42.37246202, 42.37246202, 42.33428841, 42.32930278, 
42.32930278, 42.28310122, 42.33783948, 42.33783948, 42.33783948, 
42.31210601, 42.33103377, 42.32929812, 42.33130578, 42.33263617, 
42.3300746, 42.32290252, 42.34128751, 42.33126177, 42.37663167, 
42.34382776, 42.2997787, 42.29524857, 42.29524857, 42.29524857, 
42.29524857, 42.32974821)), row.names = c(NA, 100L), class = "data.frame")
>
```

Comment: `ggplot2` works in accordance with grammar of graphics.  You haven't added appropriate layer to visualise

Comment: calling `ggplot` will never draw any plot. You have to add a `geom_***`.

Comment: Hi Guilherme. It may be better to read a brief introductory text on ggplot. There's a friendly comprehensive introduction on [this site](http://r-statistics.co/Complete-Ggplot2-Tutorial-Part1-With-R-Code.html) which also answers your question within the first few paragraphs.

Comment: i just updated the question, even with geom_point() the plot is not working

Comment: We need to see more of your data. Can you post a reproducible sample of your data. Something like `dput(head(drug_caseslat, n = 100))` or `dput(drug_caseslat[sample(1:nrow(drug_caseslat), size = 100),])`. Paste the results into your question. From the `str()` it looks like your data may only have a few unique points.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks for all the help guys! I finally made the right plot and ill leave the solution here:

```
drug_cases_lat_long<-filter(drug_violation_cases, drug_violation_cases$Latitude>=42 | drug_violation_cases$Longitude<= -40)
```

So this filter was to select all coordinates that fit the range of all the values so that no extreme points could break the plot.

```
drug_cases_unique<-unique.data.frame(drug_caseslat)
```

then checked for repeated values just like Javier suggested

```
drug_cases_unique <- data.frame("Longitude" = drug_cases_lat_long$Longitude,  "Latitude" = drug_cases_lat_long$Latitude, stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
```

and created a new data frame with these values

```
g<-ggplot(data = drug_cases_unique,aes(x = Longitude, y = Latitude))+
    geom_point()
```

then i used `ggplot()` with `geom_point()` to make the plot.

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
ggplot(drug_caseslat) + geom_point(aes(x = Longitude, y = Latitude))
```

In addition, it seems that your dataframe contains only repeated values. This would indeed explain why you only see a small number of points...

Comment: i`ve tried that and still just two points, and about the repeated values you might be right, is there a way to use a distinct() in this case?

Comment: To keep only the unique values, try unique.data.frame(drug_caseslat). It will remove all the duplicates

Comment: It should be noted, that this will make a plot with "degrees" in each axis where recipients will likely expect an axis ratio so that "degrees" could be replaced by "kilometers". One degree in longitude equals a different amount of kilometers then one degree in latitude. The original poster should google `coord_map` and `coord_quickmap`.